# Show/hide div based on URL - works locally but not on live server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using some jQuery to show/hide a div based on a URL parameter (?rp=):

```
$(function () {
      if (document.location.href.indexOf('rp') > -1) {
          $('#rphide').hide();               
       } else {
          $('#rphide').show();
       }
 });
```

It works locally and on a development server, however on the live server the div is permanently hidden EVEN if there's no ?rp= in the querystring. I'm confused as to why this is happening? Thanks.

Comment: Give an example URL and show me your header includes. Also, are there any errors in console?

Comment: Any errors in the console? Is jquery installed on your productive Server?

Comment: Live URL: http://partners.moneycorp.com/briefing jQuery 1.10.1 is referenced, there's errors in the console but not relating to the show/hide script I think

Comment: your step2 div is also hidden, making rphide visible will not make any effect until parent is visible

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to find issue with such details but here is another approach to do the same.

you are trying to search string "rp" in url, which is not good in case if you have rp in domain name. so better approach would be find query in url.

Use this function to get param.

```
$(function () {
      if (getQueryStringParamByName('rp') != "") {
          $('#rphide').hide();               
       } else {
          $('#rphide').show();
       }
 });


function getQueryStringParamByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```